# How customize GCKUICastInstructionsViewController from Google chromecast SDK?

Tags: chromecast, uiappearance

I need just to move button, make is transparent, make text capitalized.
Is it possible to achive this with UIApperance protocol or need to create its own controller?

Comment: Well, check this [thread](http://help.ooyala.com/video-platform/concepts/chromecast_setup_html_interface.html) if it can help you. It uses HTML and Javascript to customize the application. Within the body of the HTML page, you can modify various divs to make changes to the UI. For more information, here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#Styled) from the Google Cast documentation on how to style the receiver.